# Display HTML from Entity Framework in the View

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some html stored in a field I'm passing to my view, and as one would expect it is encoded by default in the scaffolded view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Template)
```

So in my limited C# experience, I went to use the raw data:

```
@Html.Raw(model => model.Template)
```

Which throws an error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a
>   delegate type

However none of the questions on that error seem to make sense with my situation, at least to my limited knowledge.

Comment: @ocanal The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HtmlHelper.Raw Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) takes just one parameter which is string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Template)
```